# postgresql vs postgresql-server-dev package

Tags: apt, package-management, postgresql

What is the difference between postgresql and postgresql-server-dev packages. What are the purposes served by installing different packages and what are the use-cases of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postgresql-server-dev` contains the header files and other components required to compile PostgreSQL extensions. Extensions are add-ons that get loaded into the PostgreSQL server. The majority of people only use extensions from postgresql-contrib or those like PostGIS that're already packaged, so you probably don't need this package. It's harmless if installed though.

Answer (score 0):

[postgresql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql) is a metapackage that installs the latest version of postgresql, but there seems to be no such package as [postgresql-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-server&searchon=names&section=all).

Comment: Sorry I just meant `postgresql-server-dev`